# How to play a video from file path in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, avplayer

I have recorded a video from my app which saves the video in Photos app in iPhone. The file path of the video saved is:

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0A8F1D57-7336-4D52-8B64-928C381DBC4F/Documents/2022-04-14@14-26-59GMT+05:00ARVideo.mp4

How can I play the video from the file path in AVPlayer?

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    playVideo()
}

private func playVideo() {
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0A8F1D57-7336-4D52-8B64-928C381DBC4F/Documents/2022-04-14@14-26-59GMT+05:00ARVideo.mp4", ofType: "mp4") else { return}
    
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
    
    let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
    vc.player = player
    
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: Please let us know what have you tried already so that we can assist you further

Answer (score 0):

```
import AVKit

func playVideo(){
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(video url string) ?? URL(fileURLWithPath: "") )
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    self.addChild(playerController)
    self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
    playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
    playerController.exitsFullScreenWhenPlaybackEnds = true
    player.play()
}
```

Comment: i have placed the file path url as string but the player doesn't play any video, it's just a black screen and the loader keeps loading

Answer (score 0):

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    playVideo()
}
// if u have video in app directory/ document directory 
private func playVideo() {
 guard let url = URL(string: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0A8F1D57-7336-4D52-8B64-928C381DBC4F/Documents/2022-04-14@14-26-59GMT+05:00ARVideo.mp4") 
 else {
    print("url not exist")
    return
    } 
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
    vc.player = player
    present(vc, animated: true)
  }

// if u have video locally that u put in ur project then
    private func playVideoFromLocal() {
        guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file_example_MOV_480_700kB", withExtension: "mov") else {return}
        let player = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
        vc.player = player
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The path of the documents changes for the app each time it is launched, which changes the first part of the URL.

Try the following updated function to get the current location of the file:

```
private func playVideo() {
      let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
      let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath.appendingFormat("/your-video-name-here.mp4")))
      let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
      let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
      vc.player = player
      present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: i tried this and placed the name of the mp4 file from the above link which is "2022-04-15@11-58-36GMT+05:00ARVideo.mp4" but still nothing plays in the avplayer

Comment: Did you try adding the slash before the file name like "/2022-04-15@11-58-36GMT+05:00ARVideo.mp4"?

Comment: i added the "/" as well but nothing changes

Comment: try to add vc.player?.play() before presenting the VC

Comment: I already did that, it keeps loading as if I couldn't find the file. The video itself is saved in the Photos app